# Parse 2 RSS feeds in app delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rss

I'm following a tutorial and it's working fine but if I wanted to parse 2 RSS feeds it seems to overwrite one array instead of saving them in the respective arrays.

This is in my delegate:

```
NSURL *url2 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"myRSSFEED1"];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser1 = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url2];

//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser1 *parser1 = [[XMLParser1 alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser1 setDelegate:parser1];

//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL successs = [xmlParser1 parse];

if(successs)
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
 //VIDS
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"MYRSSFEED2"];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

that parses feed 1, allocates it to the array then parses 2 and seems to overwrite the first insteaf of using the second array that are defined as

```
@synthesize pics;
@synthesize books;
```

And saved in my XMLParser & XMLParser1

I can't figure out how to stop it from overwriting.

Here is my XMLParsers too:

```
   - (void)parsers:(NSXMLParser *)parsers didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        //Initialize the array.
        appDelegate2.pics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {

        //Initialize the book.
        apics = [[BookPhoto alloc] init];

        //Extract the attribute here.
        apics.bookID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

        NSLog(@"Reading HAVid value :%i", apics.bookID);
    }

    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parsers:(NSXMLParser *)parsers foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}

- (void)parsers:(NSXMLParser *)parsers didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"])

        return;

    //There is nothing to do if we encounter the Books element here.
    //If we encounter the Book element howevere, we want to add the book object to the array
    // and release the object.
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {
        [appDelegate2.pics addObject:apics];


        [apics release];
        apics = nil;
    }
    else 
        [apics setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

And my XMLParser.m

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        //Initialize the array.
        appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {

        //Initialize the book.
        aBook = [[Book alloc] init];

        //Extract the attribute here.
        aBook.bookID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

        NSLog(@"Reading id value :%i", aBook.bookID);
    }

    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"])
        return;

    //There is nothing to do if we encounter the Books element here.
    //If we encounter the Book element howevere, we want to add the book object to the array
    // and release the object.
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {
        [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];

        [aBook release];
        aBook = nil;
    }
    else 
        [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

Any help on this would be brilliant,

Comment: Which array is getting overwritten?

Comment: It would help to show us the part in the delegate where it processes the second feed.

Comment: @Chris Gregg it only seems to save to the books array not pics

Comment: @sosborn it is in there: `NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"MYRSSFEED2"];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!"); `

Comment: I am really confused (sorry, it it probably just me). You have a class called XMLParser1. Is that a subclass of XMLParser?

Comment: no sorry its me confusing you, i have 2 h/m files called XMLparser.h/m and XMLparser1.h/m because once the different data has been parsed im wanting to display them in different xib's so XMLparser saves the books to my books array and XMLparser1 is suppost to save the pics feed to my pics array but it seems to load the pics then overwrites it with the books and only displays the books in the xib's tableview if you get me.

Comment: That link points to spam, please rewrite your post to it no longer depends on that link. Maybe use a spell checker in the process as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad

seems i had extra s's in parser:

```
- (void)parsers:(NSXMLParser *)parsers foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}
```

should have been:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}
```

cheers for the help tho

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting a breakpoint at the point where the array is not getting loaded, and seeing if (1) it even gets called, and (2), whether it is saving the data into the array at all.